# Term for topic type?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have several topics on my website.Topics like '50 cent', 'Game Of Thrones' and 'Apple'.Now I want to divide them by their "type" so that it will be easier for people to find topics.
E.g.

> 50 cent > Rap
>
> Apple > Operating system

What is the term for this topic "types"?

Comment: Try *categories*

Comment: Or genres could fit.

Answer (score 0):

> I have several topics on my website, such as '50 cent', each belonging to a type, such as 'Rap':
>
> 50 cent > Rap
>
> Apple > Operating system
>
> What is the term for the topic type?

I would actually use a different term for '50 cent' and 'Apple'.  I would call those *tags*.  Then the groups of related tags could be called *topics*.

Reason: *Tag* is the term often used in web development for this sort of thing.  And *topic* fits your groupings quite naturally.